# onDownloadStart parameters of webview not set? How to retrieve filename?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I have javascript code where I use anchor tag's download attribute to set filename. 
Following is my code snippet:

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = () => {
const link = <HTMLAnchorElement>windowService.document.createElement("a");
link.href = fileReader.result;
link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
link.target = "_blank";

windowService.document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
};
fileReader.readAsDataURL(testFile);
}
```

where testFile is blob of data.This code works fine with all the browsers, iOS app but not with android app.
On Android webView, onDownloadListener function is called and just url parameter is set and no other parameters are set.

```
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
// url: set as base64 encoded content
// no other attribute is set. I understand content disposition can be used to get file name but that is not set either
}
}
```

I want to get the filename assigned to file on download attribute of anchor. How can I retrieve file name for the same? I am using Android API 28 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I used `URLUtil` work well and easily

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as there is no data in contentDisposition and mimeType

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and I know chrome has the ability to do this.
Chrome has unit tests that test this https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/browser/download/download_browsertest.cc;drc=0b067632d4fd6e470cca27ceb2795e194337b30a;l=4239

Chrome on android uses this value during the download process we can see
https://source.chromium.org/search?q=GetTargetFilePath&sq=&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:chrome%2Fbrowser%2Fdownload%2Fandroid%2F

We can see that for instance it uses this value to open a completed download https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/download/DownloadUtils.java;drc=f03f9c715ccd0bb898c58a06ab5f7f3ba435164c;l=482

We can also see where it creates the download info. https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/download/android/download_manager_service.cc;drc=0e2c54333690dadb1456f0fbe30356df0b90d745;l=166

I have searched a lot, unsuccessfully on this issue, but this is the best lead I have to get this to work. Will update if I find out if we can trigger this in a webview but I have not found anyone else getting an object url name successfully thus far.

I conclude from this search that google does not actually use onDownloadStart in chromium, and instead handles it in C++ where GetTargetFilePath exists to give them this extra info. onDownloadStart exists from back when the AOSP (android open source project) browser was created, and chrome is a different platform that simply exposes information to this method but does not consume it. Thus its likely an oversight that onDownloadStart does not contain a suggested filename.

source (that chrome does not consume this method): https://source.chromium.org/search?q=%20onDownloadStart%20language:java&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc&start=21